# Documentation for Python Functions in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am studying python in Visual Studio code, and watching some tutorials I noticed a difference between the tutorial's IDE and mine.

When writing code, the tutorial's IDE will have suggestions and explanations on how to use functions.
For example, when typing mystring.replace() a popup will appear with information about what the replace function does and what kind of arguments it expects.

In my case, however, I don't see anything like that (see attached screenshot).
Is there something I am missing in the config of VS Code?

[What Intellisense suggests me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n9NuJ.png)

EDIT: I have installed the Python Extensions for VS Code.
Also, if relevant, I am using Python 3.9.0

Answer (score 7):

I found an answer to my problem.

In the settings page for Python, I changed the language server to Pylance and now I have more complete intellisense support for methods.

Answer (score 1):

You need to install [Python extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.python).

Then, once you hover with mouse over a function invocation, its documentation will appear:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your reply.

I should have mentioned that I have already installed the python extensions in VS Code. Moreover, I checked and I noticed that the for the print function, I get the same result as your screenshot.

However, for the replace methoed (just to name one) I don't see that kind of information